# Fetching data from MySQL database to html drop-down list

Tags: php

I search for answers here but haven't found a solution. 
I have also added picture of the error.
I want the data to go to the first drop-down list ( above the error)
I think the method I try to perform is also create drop-down list, am I correct?

```
           <form name="message" action="" method="post" onsubmit="" accept-charset="utf-8">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label id="senderName">שם השולח:</label>



               </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="to_user">מען:</label>
                <select name="to_user" class="form-control">
                    <option value="pick">בחר מהרשימה</option>
                        <?php

                        $sql = \mysqli_query("SELECT name From users");
                        $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);


                            echo "<select name='to_user'>";
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                                echo "<option value='". $row['name'] ."'>" .$row['name'] ."</option>" ;
                            }
                            echo "</select>" ;

                        ?>

                </select>


            </div>
```

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uOJP.png)

Comment: \mysqli_query("SELECT name From users"); what is "\" doing here...

Comment: `mysqli_query("SELECT name From users");` First parameter should be the **link** of the `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`. בהצלחה

Comment: @Poria It targets the global namespace, proabably unnecessary here, but not harmful. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

Comment: session_start() ;               include("cofing.php") ; these to are at the start suppose to connect to DB

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you,  i will read about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQLi, the first parameter of a query needs to be the database connection. Also, there's no need to add a `\` before the statement.

`$sql = \mysqli_query("SELECT name From users");` should be `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name From users");`

*Note: replace $con with your database connection variable!*

As you mentioned that you wanted the result from the database to go inside the `select` form, simply adjust your code to look like this:

```
<select name="to_user" class="form-control">
<option value="pick">בחר מהרשימה</option>
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name From users");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value='". $row['name'] ."'>" .$row['name'] ."</option>" ;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: $con , solve the issue, but how can i add it to the drop-down list instead of print it?

Comment: @user3473379 Can you elaborate?

Comment: instead of put the sql answer inside the first drop-down list, it echo it under.http://rotter.name/User_files/nor/572cca733f0ad351.jpg >> this is a print screen to demonstrate . thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3473379 If you want to create a new drop-down list, move the closing `</select>` tag from the bottom of the script to under `<option value="pick">בחר מהרשימה</option>`.

Comment: maybe it is not possible , but i want  to fetch data to this list not below. what do you think? want to say thank you for your quick response , much appreciation.

Comment: @user3473379 Are you saying you only want ONE drop-down?

Comment: you are the best :) . thank you very much . WOW thank you:!!

Comment: @user3473379 No problem!

Comment: it is possible to communicate with you via email ( job offer) ?@The Codesee

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col col-md-3">
<label for="email-input" class=" form-control-label"> Vehicle</label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-9">

<select name="car_id" id="car_id" class="form-control-label" >
<?php
$list = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `vehicle_registration` where `status`='0' ");
while ($row_ah = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_ah['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_ah['car_no']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please avoid answer with code only. Add some explanations about your solution .

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><b>Select Steam: </b></label>
<select id="study">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="">---Selected---</option>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT study FROM details";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['study']."'>".$row['study']."</option>";
    }

?>
</select>
```