# Creating Dropdown list from sql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

*The condition for "die" had been left out of my code by mistake when I copied it to the question. I put it back in.

I know this question might seem repetitive, but I have not found an answer in any of the other questions. I am trying to create a drop-down list based off a column in a database. I have tried two different ways and neither gave me correct results. Does anyone know a correct way of doing this?

The first way I saw in other StackOverflow answers ([Fetching data from MySQL database to html drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077152/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-drop-down-list), [Fetching data from MySQL database to html dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009464/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-dropdown-list)). My code is below:

```
<?php
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
 if ($connect == false)
   {
     die  ("Unable to connect to database<br>");
  }

$select = mysql_select_db('ViviansVacations');
if ($select == false)
   {
    die ("Unable to select database<br>");
  }
$query = "SELECT * FROM Destinations";
$result = mysql_query($query);
 ?>
 <select name="select1">
 <?php


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['Europe'] ."'>" .$row['Europe'] ."</option>" ;
}
?>
</select>
```

NetBeans sends me an error saying that "Text not allowed in element 'select' in this context".

The second way I tried:

```
<?php 
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root'); 
  { 
   die  ("Unable to connect to database<br>");
  }
  $select = mysql_select_db('ViviansVacations'); 
  {
   die ("Unable to select database<br>");
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Destinations";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="select1">
<?php
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $line['Europe'];?>"> <?php echo 
 $line['field'];?> </option>
<?php
  }
?>
</select>
```

This code did not produce any errors. However, inside the form were the opening php lines followed by an empty drop down box:

"); } $select = mysql_select_db('ViviansVacations'); { die ("Unable to select database
"); } $query = "SELECT * FROM Destinations"; $result = mysql_query($query); ?>

Comment: Is the file extension .php? Especially your 2nd example.

Comment: @SloanThrasher same question.

Comment: are you using the above script in a standalone .php script or calling it in an ajax scenario?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! @Sloan the mistake was that my file was .html because I had originally made it as an html form. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things, you to verify and correct.

First of all, your database connection code, that doesn't seems to be correct. I didn't see any condition on which you are suppose to invoke `die`.

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
{
die  ("Unable to connect to database<br>");
}
```

From the above code, below line will execute all the time

```
 die  ("Unable to connect to database<br>");
```

You should correct your database connection code to below :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

You can refer [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for the usage.

Also, verify your file extension is `.php`

Answer (score 1):

So there are many problems with your approach. First of all you are using a deprecated `mysql_*` functions which is bad idea and second you are not debugging your database connection properly :

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
   {
     die  ("Unable to connect to database<br>");
  }
```

In above code the die statement will always execute stopping further execution.

Also make sure the database `ViviansVacations` and table `Destinations` and column `Europe` exists with correct names(Follow standards and try to use all small letters for database/table/column naming)

The correct `mysqli_*` approach is(tested locally and the select box forms correctly) :

```
<?php
$db = 'ViviansVacations';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());


$query = "SELECT * FROM Destinations";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

?>

<select name="select1">
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Europe'] . "'>" . $row['Europe'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly your problem is database connection. Try this -

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("your_db");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be few issues:

- Use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect` because mysql is depreciated
- Make 3rd parameter as empty `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');//as per standards
- Debug your code for example: (`print_r($connect)`, execute your query in phpmyadmin, `print_r($result)` and then in loop `print_r($row)`.

At end, I am sure you will get your desired result and also you will know in detail that what was happening.

Comment: It's 'deprecated'. This may or may not have adversely affected its monetary worth.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try to use this ..The dept_id and the description u have to change according to your database .Hope this will help you

```
 <?php 
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT dept_id ,description FROM department 
  ORDER BY dept_id ASC");
  db_select($sql,"dept_id",$dept_id,"","-select Department-","","");
  ?>
```