# Problem when Fetching data from MySQL database to html drop-down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a country table with 2 columns (id and country name) and I'm using the technique mentioned in the answer to the [Fetching data from MySQL database to html drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077152/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-to-html-drop-down-list) post to fill a HTML drop-down list with the country names however, the instead of populating the list box the countries are being listed outside and below it. Any clues appreciated.

```
<tr height="29px"><td width = "200px"><b>Your Country</b></td>
            <td>
                <select name="country" id="country">
                <option value="10">First copuntry<option>
                <option value="10">Second copuntry<option>
                <option value="10">Second copuntry<option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                ?>
                    <select name="select1">
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";

                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                <?php
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This is the resulting output

[image: Screenshot showing countries listed outside the drop-down list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Remove <select name="select1"> 
and close option tag properly </option>
```